# Running npm build in a prebuild script on Vercel to build a Next.js app

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, package.json, vercel

I'm building a Markdown- / MDX- based blogging platform (see [github repo](https://github.com/dentonzh/Eggspress)). I'd like to allow users to provide their own React components that they can insert into the content section of their MDX files.

**Where I'm stuck:** I'd like to allow users to import additional dependencies that aren't already in package.json.

Perhaps a user would like to create a chart component that uses `chart.js` and `react-chartjs-2`. They could use a component that imports these dependencies by updating `package.json`.

However, for various reasons, I do not want my users to make manual edits to `package.json`.

My approach is to use a prebuild script (defined in `package.json`).

In this prebuild script, I detect which dependencies are needed based on a custom component's contents. I then run the needed `npm install` commands during prebuild using `execSync`.

The problem I encounter is that if I run any `npm install` commands, my build will fail with a slew of `Module not found` errors. These modules are a mix of first- and third-party dependencies.

I suspect I'm creating some sort of conflict or overwriting existing directories/files by running `npm install` manually from a prebuild script.

**What I've tried:**
In lieu of using `npm install`, I've tried using a combination of `npm install` with `--package-lock-only` flag and `npx add-dependenecies` (see [add-dependencies](https://github.com/arfeo/npm-add-dependencies)) to see if I can't modify `package.json` instead of installing directly.

I've also tried running `npm run build` locally and the site builds without issue.

Does anyone know what changes I could make to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to install dependencies during the build process. Well, maybe less so *during* rather than right before it.

Instead of running `npm install`, I am adding dependencies to `package.json` and `package-lock.json` first through these commands:

- `npx add-dependenecies some-package`
- `npm install some-package --package-lock-only`

I am then including `vercel.json` in the root folder of my repository. This file contains the following:

```
{
  "installCommand": "npm run prebuild && npm install"
}
```

This allows my prebuild script to run *before* Vercel installs dependencies (which, if you look at the build logs, is practically the first thing Vercel does during a build).

This seems pretty hacky and I'm not sure if what I'm doing is frowned upon. If there's a better way please comment or provide an answer!